# styling a rails button_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a rails button - add address - that i'd like to style.
At the moment i'm using bootstrap with:

"get", :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary'%>

The button is sitting within a panel-body. At the moment the width of the button is the width of the panel. Just after some advice re: setting the width and height of the button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is that you should set it to the width and height that you want it. But you haven't said what you want, or if you're having trouble with it.